# Adding and Removing Elements to Array stored as a cookie

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I am trying to figure out why this does not work. I am trying add and remove elements to an array that is stored in a cookie in a comma delimited fashion such as "1,2,3,4,5" and then echo the array size. With the arrangement of the php as I have it below, the array size is not updating after the elements have been added to the array when I run the php in a browser. It only updates the array the second time I run the php in a browser. Can someone please assist me with the correct php so that the php will add the elements and update the array size? Thank you.

```
<?
setcookie ("values", "1,2,3,4,5", time()+1000);
$aCookie = explode(",",$_COOKIE['values']);
$aCookieSize = count($aCookie);
echo $aCookieSize;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `setcookie` is used to write the specified cookie into the headers of the server's **answer**. But it does not update current **request** informations.

When you first run the script, the client do not have any cookies. Meaning `$_COOKIE` is empty. `setcookie` include your cookie into your answer header (but does not set it for `$_COOKIE`).
On the second run, the client have his cookie so `$_COOKIE` is set and `setcookie` is just overridding the cookie everytime.

Also, notice that php allow to send array with this form:

```
setcookie("cookie[three]", "cookiethree");
setcookie("cookie[two]", "cookietwo");
setcookie("cookie[one]", "cookieone");
```